# How to find a specific tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the source HTML here http://pastebin.com/rxK0mnVj . I want to check the source to contain  blz-src attribute in the Image tag, and check for src to not contain data uri and then return true or false.

For instance,

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAICRAEAOw==" data-blzsrc="http://1.resources.newtest.strawberrynet.com.edgesuite.net/4/C/lyiTlubX4.webp" width="324" height="60" alt="StrawberryNET" /></a>
```

should return `False` as `data-blzsrc` attribute is present but the `src` attribute contains `data:`

but this ,

```
<img src="http://images.akam.net/img1.jpg" data-blzsrc="http://1.resources.newtest.strawberrynet.com.edgesuite.net/4/C/lyiTlubX4.webp" width="324" height="60" alt="StrawberryNET" /></a>
```

should return `True` as it contains `data-blzsrc` attribute and the `src` does not contain `data:`

How to achieve this in BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all `img` tags and test them, use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and check the attributes, example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'))

def check_img(img):
    return 'data-blzsrc' in img.attrs and 'data' not in img.get('src', '')

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    print img, check_img(img)
```

If you want to filter out the images that fit you criteria, you can pass in an `attrs` argument to `find_all()` providing a dictionary. Set `data-blzsrc` to `True` to enforce it's existence, use a function to check that the value of `src` does not contain `data`:

```
for img in soup.find_all('img', attrs={'data-blzsrc': True, 'src': lambda x: x and 'data' not in x}):
    print img
```

Comment: The `src` should not contain `data`

Comment: @user567797 which the second solution does elegantly

Comment: Also in the second one where are we passing the html source

Comment: Oh got it , it's in soup

Comment: Your second solution breaks with this HTML http://pastebin.com/itMYaimq gives an error because The img tag in line 1885 doesn't have a src attribute. How to modify so that even if one ing tag satisfies this return True

Comment: @user567797 yup, fixed it, check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @user567797 is there anything to add here? Wondering why the answer was unaccepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find all images, and check if desired attr exists and check src attribute content. Have a look to this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAQAICRAEAOw==" data-blzsrc="http://1.resources.newtest.strawberrynet.com.edgesuite.net/4/C/lyiTlubX4.webp" width="324" height="60" alt="StrawberryNET" /></a>
<img src="http://images.akam.net/img1.jpg" data-blzsrc="http://1.resources.newtest.strawberrynet.com.edgesuite.net/4/C/lyiTlubX4.webp" width="324" height="60" alt="StrawberryNET" /></a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    #here is your desired conditions
    if img.has_attr('data-blzsrc') and not img.attrs.get('src','').startswith('data:'):
        print img
```

It prints the desired img node

```
<img alt="StrawberryNET" data-blzsrc="http://1.resources.newtest.strawberrynet.com.edgesuite.net/4/C/lyiTlubX4.webp" height="60" src="http://images.akam.net/img1.jpg" width="324"/>
```

Comment: `src` starts with `data:`

Comment: Actually the `src` should not contain `data`